# Adding a new private member variable to a class causes a memory gap for all following variable (C++17)

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I encountered a weird problem, when I modify a header file (specifically add a private member variable) I then have a weird, memory related I believe, bug.

Here is some exemple to code to illustrate:

Original header file:

```
#includes
class myClass : public otherClass1 {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    myClass(params);
private:
    std::reference_wrapper<otherClass2> _Var1;
    std::vector<QRadioButton*> _Var2;
    QComboBox * _Var3;
    size_t _Var4;
};
```

Original source file:

```
#includes
myClass::myClass(params){
    //Do stuff
    _Var4 = 5;
    //Rest of the stuff to be done
}
```

Now if add _testVar under _Var4 everything's good, but adding _testVar between _Var4 and _Var3 makes _Var4 bug, if I add _testVar under _Var2 then _Var3 and _Var4 bug.
I also noticed that if _Var3 and _Var4 bug then modifying _Var3 actually modifies _Var4.

From my (limited) understanding this is caused by a memory gap (meaning that _testVar is now _Var3 and _Var3 is _Var4 (memory wise)).

Now I'm not expecting to recieve a flat out answer for my problem here but some pointers and hints would help greatly, because I'm completely clueless right now as to why this is happening.

PS: I'm using Qt 5.15.1, not that it's related I believe but maybe it's worth mentioning.

EDIT: @markus-nm was right, it was a MOC-related issue. Clearing all of the generated outputs (forcing MOC to be re-run) solved the issue. This solution wasn't obvious to me due to the specific environment and tools I have to use at my work.

Comment: did you recompile all the code that depends on this? If not then you're seeing memory corruption because the other code isn't aware of the layout change.

Comment: Yes i did recompile everything several times, plus this issue isn't specific of my computer, a coworker reproduced it.

Comment: @Mummoc you also need to re-run QMake or CMake, so it will re-run the MOC, since your class is a QObject. Or maybe its because you have some #ifdefs in your header that are not always the same value when compiling each source file that references the header. Though not evident from your code, make sure your inheritance isnt polymorphic, because that doesnt work with QObjects.